# Redirect to home page if browser becomes idle or no activity for a certain time (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, session-timeout

I have web application. I want to redirect the browser to home page if the browser becomes idle for a certain length of time let's say 20 minutes. But if the user is active on that site let's say clicking links or reading the page or scrolling page up and down, the page will not redirect to home page since the user is not idle. Session timeout of 20 minutes is always sliding or extended. I tried to configure the the web.config and run the application in debug mode but nothing happens. After became idle for 20 minutes the application did not redirect me to home page. Please help. Here's my web.config settings.

**Web.Config**

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="20" mode="InProc" />
.....

<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="20" />
    </authentication>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those settings are server-side settings.  Once the webpage is served, the server is done caring what the client is doing with it -- saving the HTML, viewing it, already closed the browser.

You need a client-side solution.  A very basic example of this would be the following javascript code that you could run on every page load.

```
setTimeout(function()
{
window.location.href = "/"; // you can use @Url.Content("~/") inside the quotes to also get the homepage url if you'd prefer...
}, 20 * 60 * 1000); // 20 mins * 60 sec/min * 1000 ms/sec.
```

This code would indiscriminately redirect someone to the homepage after 20 minutes of idle on a page.

Most solutions will give you a JS modal dialog to reset the time and keep your session alive (by making an AJAX call to a keep alive `ping` page, for example).  But this should be enough to answer your question and get you started down picking the clientside solution that works best for you.

Comment: @eli Gassert , when  and how to call this function..??